# BASS Не правильно работает изменение громкости

Tags: c++, bass.dll

Проблема вот в чем, есть консольный плеер на бассе, и есть в ней функция изменения громкости, если ставить громкость ниже 100, то звук вообще проподает, но песня видимо играет дальше... Ну и что делать?

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <regex>


#include "bass.h"
#include "basslib.h"
using namespace mcap;

std::string b2s(bool val){
  if (val == true) return "true";
  else return "false";
}

int toInteger(std::string value){
  int num = 0, size = value.size();
  for (int i = 0, j = size; i < size; ++i) num += (value[--j]-'0')*std::pow(10,i);
  return num;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  basslib b;
  b.paused = false;
  b.playing = false;

  if(!b.initBass())
    std::cout << "BASS have problems with load, sorry..." << "\n";

  std::string songname;

  if (argc > 1)
    songname = argv[1];

  std::cout << "Current song=" << songname << "\n";

  std::string status_string = "[playing:" + b2s(b.playing)
    + " paused:" + b2s(b.paused)
    + " vol:" + std::to_string(b.gvol) + "]";

  std::cout << status_string << ">";
  std::string c = "";
  std::cin >> c;

  while (true){

    status_string = "[playing:" + b2s(b.playing) + " paused:"
      + b2s(b.paused) +" vol:" + std::to_string(b.gvol) + "]";

    if(c == "play") b.play(songname);
    else if (c == "pause") b.pause();
    else if (c == "stop") b.stop();
    else if (c == "vol"){
      std::cout << "Enter volume:";

      int gettedvol;
      std::cin >> gettedvol;
      b.setVolume(gettedvol);
    }else if (c == "e" || c == "exit" || c == "quit" || c == "q" || c == "windowsthebest"){
      return 0;
    }

    // ------------- 
    std::cout << status_string << ">";
    std::cin >> c;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

basslib.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bass.h"
namespace mcap{
  class basslib{
  public:
    bool playing = false;
    bool paused = false;
    int gvol = 0;
    HSTREAM stream;

    bool initBass();
    void play(std::string filename);
    void setVolume(int vol);
    void pause();
    void stop();
  };
}
```

basslib.cpp:

```
#include "basslib.h"

using namespace mcap;

bool basslib::initBass(){
  playing = false;
  if(BASS_Init(-1, 44100, BASS_DEVICE_3D, 0, 0)) return true;
  return false;
}

void basslib::play(std::string filename){
  if(playing == false && paused == false){
    stream = BASS_StreamCreateFile(false, filename.c_str(), 0,0,0);
    BASS_ChannelPlay(stream, false);
    playing = true;
    setVolume(100);
  }else if (playing == true && paused == true) {
    paused = false;
    BASS_ChannelPlay(stream, false);
  }else if (playing == true && paused == false) stop();
}

void basslib::pause(){
  BASS_ChannelPause(stream);
  paused = true;
}

void basslib::setVolume(int vol){
  gvol = vol;
  BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(stream, BASS_ATTRIB_VOL, gvol/100);
}

void basslib::stop(){
  BASS_ChannelStop(stream);
  playing = false;
  paused  = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо вы простреливаете себе ногу неявными преобразованиями. `BASS_SetVolume` принимает в качестве параметра объект типа `float` со значением в диапазоне [0.0 … 1.0]

Comment: а, это я игрался, изначально gvol на 100 делилось

Comment: @GENKY, а смысл делить на 100? Все значения, что будут ниже 100, давать 0, по этому и звука нет.

Comment: ну в bass.net у меня так работало... Басс ведь принимает значения в духе 0.5, 1.0, так ведь? А мы привыкли к 50, 100, или я не прав?

Answer (score 2):

Я нашел ответ, точнее мне подсказали товарищи VTT и B1aZe, я забыл что для уровня звука я использовал тип int что неправильно, т.к. допустим 58 при делении на 100 не будет целочисленным, и оно станет нулем.

Comment: Именно это мы с VTT, вам и пытались донести, все числа, что ниже 100, будут давать 0, так как принимаемый тип `int`

Comment: @B1aZe от вас я это и понял!